# Complex integral with $\log(z)$

Tags: complex-analysis, logarithms

I have problem with the complex integral : $\int_{[1,i]}{\log (z)dz}$. I try to use primitive function of $\log (z)$ which is $z\log(z)-z$.

Comment: You need a branch of the primitive analytic on an open containing $[1,i]$, then its derivative will be a branch of $\log (z)$ analytic on that open, uniquely determined by $\log(1)$

Comment: Okey... So what should I do?

Comment: Parameterize your segment : $z=(1-t)+it$ for $t \in [0,1]$ with $dz=(-1+i)dt$ and integrate with repect to $t$.

Comment: Will the answer be with $i2k\pi$?

Comment: It depends on which branch of log you use.  But it won't be $i2k\pi$ for any branch analytic in a neighbourhood of $[1,i]$.

Comment: So I need to use parametrization or calculate the primitive of $\log(z)$? I have two different results in these cases :/